# eloquent using scopeSomeName() vs someName()

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

whats the difference between using in eloquent

```
class SomeModel extends Model{
    public function active(){
        return $this->where('active','=',1);
    }
}
```

vs:

```
class SomeModel extends Model{
    public function scopeActive($query){
        return $query->where('active','=',1);
    }
}
```

I can use them both the same way and I am getting the same results...

```
$SomeModel->active()->get();
```

is there any advantage to the "scope prepend" way?

edit:
I am referring to this from the docs
http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#query-scopes

> Scopes allow you to define common sets of constraints that you may
>   easily re-use throughout your application. For example, you may need
>   to frequently retrieve all users that are considered "popular". To
>   define a scope, simply prefix an Eloquent model method with scope.

but like I said I can do the same thing without prefix with "scope" so why to bother at all?

Comment: Maybe it improves the readability of your code stating that the function is a scope...

Comment: Using a scope gives you access to the Builder object. This allows you to control things like bindings and access methods which aren't available using `$this` on the model itself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access scope query when calling static

```
Model::action()->get();
```

you can't do that using common method. For me like Armanasan said, it will give me readibility of my code.

Answer (score 0):

The `scope` allows you to nicely chain methods (via the argument `$query` instead of requiring `$this`).

As @Benyamin Maengkom mentionned, the method can then also be used statically.

Comment: thanks, I think Benyamin Maengkom is right.. I can also chain methods the same way without the scope